# JBehave BDD - sleep between steps

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

I am currently on writing some JBehave BDD test. Is there a way to give a sleep time between the execution of two steps (@When - @Then) or set a delay before starting the next step? Can this be set via a property or somethinf? Thank you!

---

UPDATE

I updated my story file as follows:

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Scope: STEP
Given a step causing delay in execution
```

And then I have a scenario:

```
Scenario: T1363 - doSomething
Given blablabla
When blablaaaaa
Then blaaa

Examples:
|   status
|   bla
```

When I run my code, I got following console output:

[image]

Why am I getting SCENARIO scope?

Comment: JBehave Lifecycle: https://jbehave.org/reference/stable/lifecycle.html may help you, you can put step sleeping for some time to STEP scope

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do not really get how it works to create a step scope... I updated my question. Any idea?

Comment: Which JBehave version do you use?